# Не выводить поле в шаблоне, если оно пустое

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую Вордпресс и плагин ACF для создания доп. полей на сайте. В админке есть поле ссылка на Facebook.

В шаблоне сайта оно выводится такой конструкцией:

```
<?php the_field('facebook', 'option'); ?>
```

Хочу составить условие для вывода, чтобы в случае незаполненного поля оно не выводилось в шаблоне. Пробовал такой вариант:

```
<?php if( (the_field('facebook', 'option'))!="") { ?>
----
<?php } ?>
```

Если не пусто, то вывести. Если пусто, то ничего выводиться не должно.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно не отображать блок на странице если он не заполнен в админке.
Вот код, что я делаю не правильно, спасибо. ?! <?php if(get_field('seo-two-block')) { ?> <section class="seo__text two_col"> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <?php $seoBlock = get_field('seo-two-block'); if( !empty($seoBlock) ) : { echo $seoBlock; } ?> <div class="section__title"> <h3><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-title']; ?></h3> <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-subtitle']; ?></p> </div> <div class="seo__left column"> <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-left']; ?></p> </div> <div class="seo_

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/520869)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
<?php if( !isset(the_field('facebook', 'option'))) { ?>
```

если не получается покажите что дает

```
<?php var_dump(the_field('facebook', 'option'))  ?>
```

Comment: <?php var_dump(the_field('facebook', 'option'))  ?> - отдает NULL, если поле не заполнено. www.facebook.comNULL, если заполнено. 1 вариант дал ошибку - Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: тогда вот так сделайте <?php if( (the_field('facebook', 'option'))!="NULL") { ?> или <?php if( (the_field('facebook', 'option'))!=NULL) { ?>

Comment: Если поле было не заполнено, то условие <?php if( (the_field('facebook', 'option'))!=NULL) { ?> отработало и ничего не вывелось.
Когда поле заполнил, произошло следующее:
Содержимое внутри условия не вывелось (Иконка + ссылка), зато просто вывелась заполненная ссылка на facebook, похоже что содержимое вывелось на эта сравнения.

Comment: последнюю фразу не понял.

Comment: <?php $facebook = get_field('facebook', 'option'); 
if($facebook!="") { ?>
-----     
 <?php } ?> - отработал такой вариант, использовав вместо the_field, get_field. Большое спасибо за помощь и отзывчивость!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

$href= the_field('facebook', 'option');
// либо $href= get_field('facebook', 'option');

if( !empty($href) ) {
    echo $href;
}
?>
```

второй вариант

```
<?php 

$href = the_field('facebook', 'option');
// либо $href = get_field('facebook', 'option');

if( !empty($href) ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $href; ?>">ссылка на фейсбук</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```